# Displaying textblock properly on a pivotitem

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm having a hard time trying to display how my textblock look like in the pivotitem. How do i make it look like the default one where u will get when u create a pivot project?

Thanks! :)

```
private void LoadFromLocalStorage()
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        string[] fileNames = store.GetFileNames();

        foreach (string s in fileNames)
        {

            TextBlock txt = new TextBlock() { Text = s };
            container.Children.Add(txt);


            //PivotItem pitem = new PivotItem(); //create pivotitem                
            //pitem.Content =  //set pivotitem content
            //MyPivot.Items.Add(pitem);//Add pivotitem to your pivot

        }
    }
}
```

XAML

```
 <controls:Pivot Title="MY APPLICATION">
            <!--Pivot item one-->
            <controls:PivotItem Header="item1">

                    <StackPanel x:Name="container"></StackPanel>
            </controls:PivotItem>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit the `HeaderTemplate` of the Pivot. Here's the default template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding}" d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

use like

```
<controls:Pivot Title="MY APPLICATION" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate1}">
```

edit: if you're trying to display your items in the PivotItem, you should use a ListBox.

Add this to the top of the Page XAML.

```
 <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Margin="0,0,1,0" Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Inside your PivotItem, add a listbox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbFiles" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate1}">

                </ListBox>
```

Then, change your function for getting filenames:

```
private void LoadFromLocalStorage()
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        string[] fileNames = store.GetFileNames();
        var files = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        foreach (string s in fileNames)
        {
            files.Add(s);
        }
        lbFiles.ItemsSource = files;
    }
}
```

Here, the listbox 'ItemSource' is set to the list of filenames.

If this isn't familiar to you, you should go through some WP7 tutorials. It is pretty basic.

http://create.msdn.com/en-us/education/quickstarts

Comment: Where do i put this 

<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding}" d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

Comment: In the page Resources, or App Resources. App resources is global, while page is specific to a given page. For example, Open App.xaml.cs, and paste that into
    <Application.Resources>
    </Application.Resources>

Comment: Hmm it says the property 'LayoutOverrides' was not found in type ' Textblock'

Comment: The d: namespace is a part of expression blend. You can add that namespace, but if you're not using expression blend, just delete the property alltogether.

Comment: @RainbowHat the namespace is "xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008", you would add this to the top of the file with the other namespaces

Comment: I'm sry but it doesnt work >.< Now i cant even 'click' it haha >.< Sorry

Comment: @RainbowHat sorry click what? The PivotItem header? Did you retemplate it previously to be a button?

Comment: Nope :x But when i click it changed its colour :x last time not now :x I tried adding the namespace too , its saying its not resolved. Hmm this is taking half of my day xD

Comment: HMm any other way to display the name of the image file? :\ just wanna make sure its clickable & visually appealing to eyes >.<

Comment: @RainbowHat I'm confused. Are you looking to update the look of a Header on a pivot, or are you trying to display a list of files inside of a Pivot?

Comment: I'm trying to display a list of stuff inside the Pivot item >.<

I have pictures in storage and want to retrieve their file name  and display it so when user clicks on it , it will load the picture

Comment: Thank you! Now i'm left with giving it an event handler
Something like this right?
 private void TextList_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
Afterthat i'm not so sure >.< would be nice if you can help too :P
Anw thanks ! :D <3

Comment: @RainbowHat http://www.snippetbank.net/detail/snippetdetail/16-csharpmobile/1-controls/502-ListBox-SelectionChanged-Example.html

Comment: Hmm Hey willmel , can you look @ this thread? THanks! :D 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053420/tap-gesture-as-select-for-listbox