# Tap gesture as select, for listbox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1

How do i create an event for it to detect that the user tapped on the item in listbox

```
<!--Pivot Control-->
<controls:Pivot Title="MY APPLICATION">
    <!--Pivot item one-->
    <controls:PivotItem Header="item1">
        <ListBox x:Name="lbFiles" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate1}">
        </ListBox>
    </controls:PivotItem>
    <!--Pivot item two-->
    <controls:PivotItem Header="item2">
    </controls:PivotItem>
</controls:Pivot>
```

Code behind

```
 private void lbFile_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            selected = lbFiles.SelectedItem.ToString();
            general item = new general();
            item.viewimage(selected);
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/View.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
```

*headache* THanks! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not attaching the SelectionChanged event. You have a function for it there, but you're not making anything use it.

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbFiles" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" SelectionChanged="lbfile_SelectionChanged" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate1}">
        </ListBox>
```

You need to attach events so that they are used. You should go through the first few WP7 tutorials on create.msdn - you'll find a lot of what you need to get started and feel more comfortable about things like this.